# Cannot clear an ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a filter panel and I get a data from it and from my Firebase Realtime Database using a callback. I have an if/else block. If `answer.size() == 0` is true (answer is a list of filters' values), I fill my adapter with a list. If false, I want to clear an adapter and have an empty ListView.
Here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        verifyStoragePermissions(getActivity());
        ArrayList<PlayerRating> finalRatingList = new ArrayList<PlayerRating>();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_fragment, container, false);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.convertButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                alertSingleChoiceItems(); ;

            }});
        Database base = new Database();
        base.readTournaments(new Database.TournamentsCallback() { //reading data from Firebase using callback
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onCallback(ArrayList<TournamentParameters> tournamentsList,
                                   ArrayList<String> tournamentsNames, ArrayList<String> answer) {
                ArrayList<PlayerRating>ratingList = new ArrayList<PlayerRating>();
                ArrayList<TournamentParameters> editableTournamentsList = new ArrayList<TournamentParameters>(tournamentsList);
                PlayerRatingAdapter adapter = new PlayerRatingAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.rating_adapter_item, 
                        new ArrayList<PlayerRating>());
                ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingListView);
                if (answer.size() == 0) { // answer.size() is a size of an ArrayList with filters' values
                    ratingList.clear();
                    finalRatingList.clear();
                    HashMap<String, Integer> rating = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    //tournamentsList filling
                    ...

                    //ratingList filling
                    ...
                    
                    //ratingList sorting
                    ...
                    adapter = new PlayerRatingAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.rating_adapter_item, ratingList);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_listview_header,
                            listview, false);
                    listview.addHeaderView(header);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                else {
                    ratingList.clear();
                    finalRatingList.clear();
                    adapter.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.d("okey", "cleared!");
                    }
                Button filtersTV = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.filtersTV);
                filtersTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showFragment();

                    }
                });    
                }
        });
        return view;
}
```

showFragment method:

```
private void showFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (!fragment.isAdded()) {

            transaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment, "filter");
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Also when I set the filters method `dismissFragment()` works (it is responsible for going back from my filter panel fragment to my fragment with ListView):

```
public void dismissFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
            transaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment, "filter");
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, new RatingFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        //FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //fm.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
```

The problem is the fact that my adapter is not cleared. When code goes to `else` block and

```
ratingList.clear();
finalRatingList.clear();
adapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Log.d("okey", "cleared!");
```

works (I even have an expected message in my LogCat), nothing is changed - my ListView remains the same, nothing is cleared.
What should I change in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different instances of adapter in your code. One outside if/else and one in 'if block'.
That's why when you clear it in 'else block' it's not the same adapter. And nothing happens.

Instrad of initializing adapter again in 'if block' just update it and your cide will work.